# Onclick function doesnt work

Tags: jquery, onclick

I tried creating this script and it works when I call the function oncall but when I create a button and use the onclick function the script doesn't run.

```
var i = 0;

function increase() {

    var amount = parseInt($('.amount').text());

    i = amount;
    var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * amount);
    var counter = window.setInterval(function () {
        if (i == amount + random) {
            window.clearInterval(counter);
        }
        document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = i++;
    }, 10);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7MLK5/2/

Comment: If you move the code to the `<head>` in the fiddle it works: http://jsfiddle.net/7MLK5/4/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `increase` function is not in global scope, put it in global scope and it is fine.

In fiddler LHS panel, in the second dropdown `onload` is selected by default, this will make fiddler to add all the script inside a `onload` handler making them local in scope so when your inline `onclick` handler tries to look for the method in the global scope it will not find it there. An easy fix is to select `No Wrap - In Body/Head` in the dropdown - it will not wrap the contents in another function making them in global scope.

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/t7k7D/)

Also since you are using jQuery, I would prefer to add the event handlers using jQuery rather than using  inline scripting

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `onclick` event attributes. They are outdated and ugly, not to mention flaky. As you are using jQuery anyway, use that to bind your events:

```
$('.button').click(increase);
```

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/7MLK5/5/)

Answer (score 0):

That is because JSFiddle puts your code inside a function called window.load. So you won't see the functions you create inside the javascript panel because they are encapsulated.

Here I've updated your code and moved the function outside the js panel

http://jsfiddle.net/7MLK5/2/

```
<div class="button" onclick="increase();">Increase</div>
<p id="result" class="amount">50</p>
<script type="text/javascript">

    var i = 0;
function increase() {
    var amount = parseInt($('.amount').text());
    i = amount;
    var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * amount);
    var counter = window.setInterval(function () {
        if (i == amount + random) {
            window.clearInterval(counter);
        }
        document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = i++;
    }, 10);
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/AZgyj/)

The below code will work..

**JQUERY**

```
var i = 0;
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".button").click(function(){
    increase();
    });
});
function increase() {
    var amount = parseInt($('.amount').text());
    i = amount;
    var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * amount);
    var counter = window.setInterval(function () {
        if (i == amount + random) {
            window.clearInterval(counter);
        }
        document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = i++;
    }, 10);
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="button">Increase</div>
<p id="result" class="amount">50</p>
```

**CSS**

```
.button {
    width: 94px;
    height: 44px;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 25px;
    margin-right: 25px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 44px;
    color: whitesmoke;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    cursor: pointer;
}
.button:first-child {
    background-color: #3498db;
    border: 3px solid #2980b9;
}
```